# Substitution in parametric resonance

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was reading parametric resonance from Landau.
The equaion of motion of harmonic oscillator in case of time dependent $m$ and $k$ is
$$\frac{d}{dt}(m\dot{x})+kx=0$$
We introduce a new variable $\tau$ such that $d\tau=dt/m(t)$.
The resulting equation now is
$$d^2x/d\tau^2+mkx=0$$
My question was how the above equation was obtained. One way I can see is to do the following
$$\frac{1}{m}\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(m\frac{1}{m}\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)+kx=0$$
And then simplify to obtain the required equation but is this the right way to do, cause I am substituting variables in an operator here differential operator?

Comment: your confusion is because the overloaded use of the dependent variable $x$, write $x(t) = y(\tau)$ then do differentiation with respect to $t$ using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

your equation is:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(m(t)\,\frac{dx}{dt}\right)+k\,x=0\tag 1$$

with
$$d\tau=\frac{dt}{m(t)}\quad\Rightarrow\quad dt=m(t)\,d\tau$$

substitute $~dt~$ in Eq. (1)
$$\frac{1}{m(t)}\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(m(t)\,\frac{dx}{m(t)\,d\tau}\right)+k\,x=0\\
\frac {d^2 x}{d\tau^2}+m(t)\,k\,x=0$$